# Facebook JS sdk Error in retrieving email in login response

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth, user-permissions

i ma using Facebook JavaScript SDK for my FB iframe app. i wnat to get teh user email id in login state

here is my code......

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Mettter</title>
  </head>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>

   <script>
   FB.init({appId:'1*********', xfbml: true, cookie: true, oauth: true, fbconnect: false});                 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                 FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                      alert('Your name is... ' + resp.name);
                     alert('Your email is.... ' + resp.email);

                    });
               } else {
                 // no user session available, someone you dont know
                 alert("i dont know ");
                 FB.api('/me', function(res) {
                      alert('Your name is ' + res.name);
                     alert('Your email is ' + res.email);

                    });

               }
             });

         </script>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>



  </body>
</html>
```

now when i hit my app URL.. i see a log in to app window i click log in  then i see allow window asking for publish streams and when i click allow the the else alert is fired and conatains **undefined** instead of name and email and the URL contains this message

```
http://apps.facebook.com/palmchipprojecta/?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.#_=_
```

i am not getting whats wrong in it??